# dojo Widget Id Conflict

Tags: dojo

I write ctor's of My dojo Widgets like this.

```
    constructor: function(params){
        var r = this.inherited(arguments);
        this.params = params;
        //other ctor works
        return r;
    }
```

I instanciate the widget with JSON response as ctor argument. like `new MyWidget(res)`
and the JSON response contains an `id` attribute like `{id: 5, text: 'Hallo'}`

Now `_WidgetBase` constructor treats this id as Widget Id and throws `Tried to register widget with id==6 but that id is already registered`. cause there may be some other widget that is also getting `id: 6` for *another* subject.

and I cannot change the JSON response to output like `subject_id` as it will need changing a lot of things.

and I need to get that id after widget instantiation.

So What would be a good design to handle this problem ?

Comment: Does `res` actually contain any parameters for _WidgetBase? I mean is there a reason you can't just do `new MyWidget({myParams: res})` and `this.params = params.myParams;` in the constructor?

Comment: Yes I can do it. However the classes that are already doing it in the previous needs to be changed to `this.params.myParams` which is a lot of work. and it doesn't look good too. Isn't there any better alternative ?

Comment: What about `res.subject_id = res.id; delete res.id;` before the instantiation then? Admittedly, this doesn't look very good either :P

Comment: Yes Its not a good design even. The correct solution would be asking `_WidgetBase` to ignore the `id` attribute that comes from params and assign its self generated `id` instead.

Comment: I agree with you the latter is several different kinds of wrong. I think perhaps overriding the ubiquitous widget id in itself is a bad design though. It may be an indicator that you are mixing your model and your view - in this case by leaking the model namespace into the view namespace. 
With that in mind, I think `new MyWidget({subject: res})` and `this.subject = params.subject;` is the cleanest way.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question! Here is my solution: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/z9u8a/

```
var Widget = declare(_WidgetBase, {

    postscript: function() {
        var id = arguments[0]["id"];
        delete arguments[0]["id"];
        this.inherited(arguments);
        this.params.id = id;
    },

    constructor: function(params) {                      
        // your constructor here
    }            

});

var widget1 = new Widget({ id: 1, text: 'Hallo 1'});
var widget2 = new Widget({ id: 1, text: 'Hallo 2'});
```

**EDIT:** I did some clean up, so all you need is to add `postscript` method.

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually need to map the json properties to your widget directly ?
If not, then just have a json property in your widget, and when instantiating : new myWidget({jsonObj:res});
then you could have a getJsonId() function that would return this.jsonObj.id;